# Add a key named FacebookClientToken to your Info.plist, and add your client token as its value while running Flutter app in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, macos, android-studio

I am getting errors while running my app in Xcode / iOS via Android Studio. The app is working on Android devices but on iOS, it's freezing in Splash Screen.

So, I have to try many things to solve this error. Finally, I solve this & the answer is below.

Answer (score 4):

A major change in Xcode & iOS Development in Flutter is that **info.plist** you have to add some more information for Facebook Authentication. According to Facebook's documentation, I need to add the following to **info.plist**:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>3088*******</string>
<key>FacebookClientToken</key>. //You have to add this key 
<string>3088986********</string> // And client token value from facebook developer page
```

This will solve my issue. while running the app in iOS Xcode & Mac. Hope This will solve your issue too.